# Accessing tooltips with Vimperator

Tags: firefox, fedora, javascript, vimperator, tooltip

I use [Navigation popups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Navigation_popups) on Wikipedia which is very handy to not to jump over multiple articles opening them in new tabs.

It requires a `mouseover` action to display the short preview of the article.

I want them to be displayed using Vimperator as I don't usually use the mouse or may not have one relying solely on keyboard.

I tried to get them displayed through `;;` (a feature called *Focus hint*) but it just focuses on the link and does not work (doesn't perform a JavaScript `mouseover` function on them from my understanding).

So I wonder how to implement that on Vimperator.

I've never used Vimperator plugins before, if they exist in first place, and don't know if it is possible through another shortcut, command, or through reconfiguration.

Comment: This would be something super-helpful and that I haven't cracked yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across on Web, and installed from the native repository of Fedora the [qutebrowser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutebrowser) which I came to love much. It provides the functionality by <kbd>;</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> shortcut. It didn't only solve my problem but also made me shift from [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) to qutebrowser for its focus on keyboard and shortcuts, and *minimalism*.